# uWSGI ignores socket option in config

Tags: ubuntu, uwsgi

I'm use Ubuntu 12.04.1 on AWS EC2 Micro instance and trying to set up simple Flask app with uWSGI and nginx. And I faced something strange with uWSGI configuration.

Here is my `app.conf`:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/tmp.sock
plugins = python27
chdir = /home/ubuntu/app
pythonpath = ..
module = app:app
virtualenv = /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app
```

uWSGI did not create socket file after restart nor if I run it manually with `uwsgi -i /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/app.conf`, here the log:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 1.0.3-debian (64bit) on [Sat Mar 16 06:54:39 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 17 July 2012 02:26:54
current working directory: /home/ubuntu/app
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
The -s/--socket option is missing and stdin is not a socket.
```

But when I add `-s` argument, all works fine:

```
uwsgi -i /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/app.conf -s /tmp/tmp.sock

*** Starting uWSGI 1.0.3-debian (64bit) on [Sat Mar 16 06:56:04 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 17 July 2012 02:26:54
current working directory: /home/ubuntu/app
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/tmp.sock fd 3
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 18023, cores: 1)
```

So, seems like uWSGI is ignoring `socket` option which set in app config file?

---

This happens only with ini-formatted config files - all ok with same configuration written in XML. Looks like a bug.

Comment: your uwsgi version is too old. You can try newer version with: `sudo pip install uwsgi` . It install `uwsgi-1.4.9` on my  Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Comment: @HVNSweeting sad, but updating didn't help - same result for `uwsgi-1.4.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uWSGI expect only some extension like `.ini`, `.xml`...

Renaming your `app.conf` file to `app.ini` will solve the problem.